# Java JTree - setSeelectionPath

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I want to select a node in my JTree from my code. I am calling the method setSelectionPath but nothing happens. What is wrong with my code ?

```
public class test extends JFrame {

   private static DefaultMutableTreeNode  root, light, medium, dark, whiteNode;  

   private  static JTree tree;

   public static void main(String[] args){

    new test();

    tree.setSelectionPath(new TreePath(whiteNode.getPath()));



   }

   public test(){


      root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("colors");

      tree = new JTree(root);


      light =  addFile("light", root); 
      medium = addFile("medium", root);
      dark = addFile("dark", root);

      //Add leaf nodes to light
      whiteNode = addFile("white", light);

      //Add leaf nodes to medium
      addFile("green", medium); 
      addFile("yellow", light);
      addFile("orange", light);
      addFile("violet", light); 

     this.getContentPane().add(tree);
     this.setVisible(true);
     this.validate();
     this.validateTree();

   }


    private DefaultMutableTreeNode addFile(String fname, DefaultMutableTreeNode parentFolder){

    DefaultMutableTreeNode newFile = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(fname);
    parentFolder.add(newFile);

    return newFile; 

}
```

}

Thanks in advance

Comment: You may want to add your `tree` to [`JFrame`'s `ContentPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) and not directly to the frame.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't fix anything.

Comment: Is this your **entire** code?

Comment: @PM77-1, yes it's the entire code.

Answer (score 2):

The reference used by the constructor in this statement

```
TreePath t = new TreePath("colors, light, white");
```

needs to refer to the last path component and should be of type `TreePath` rather than a `String`:

```
tree.setSelectionPath(new TreePath(whiteNode.getPath()));
```

where `whiteNode` is assigned

```
whiteNode = addFile("white", light);
```

Read: [How to Use Trees](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html)

Comment: Sounds like something very minor - update your question with updated code and we'll have a look...

Comment: I got It now :D Thank you again